# Cmake - Undefined reference to function

Tags: c++, c, cmake, undefined-reference

I'm trying to build my application. It's organized as following:

```
-ClipsCore
  |-agenda.c
  |-agenda.h
  |-envrnmnt.c
  |-engrnmnt.h
  |-clips.h  
  |-....
-src
  |-clipsDemo.cpp
-build
-CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (clipsDemo)
set(MY_CPP_FILES  src/clipsDemo.cpp)
file(GLOB CLIPS_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ClipsCore/*.c)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ClipsCore)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ClipsCore)
add_library(clipslib ${CLIPS_SRC})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MY_CPP_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} clipslib)
```

When I build, I got errors like the following:

```
undefined reference to `CreateEnvironment()'
```

Although this function found in **envrnmnt.c** file which should be linked to the executable as far as I understand. I tried to build the ClipsCore library using `add_library` then tried to link it to the executable using `target_link_libraries`.
What is wrong with my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: it looks ok on the face of it, except you don't need the `link_directories()` line - cmake knows where to find the library target. did you `extern "C"` the definitions of c functions?

Comment: Thanks @RichardHodges. `extern "C"` was missing. Now everything is working fine.
Could you add this as an answer?